# How to create mySQL summary table for data where rows contain both names and values?

Tags: mysql

I have source data in a MySQL table looking like this:

```
+----+------+-------+
| id | name | value |
+----+------+-------+
|  1 |   a  |   10  |
|  1 |   b  |    5  |
|  2 |   a  |   20  |
|  2 |   b  |    5  |
|  3 |   a  |   30  |
|  3 |   b  |    5  |
+----+------+-------+
```

I need the final result looking like this:

```
+----+----+----+
| id | a  | b  |
+----+----+----+
|  1 | 10 |  5 |
|  2 | 20 |  5 |
|  3 | 30 |  5 |
+----+----+----+
```

Should be a simple task for folks experienced in mySQL. Any suggestions?

Comment: Google for `PIVOT`.

Answer (score 0):

As @Juan mentioned, you could Google around for this.  But just in case you can't figure it out have a look at the query below.

```
SELECT id,
       MAX(CASE WHEN name = 'a' THEN value END) AS a,
       MAX(CASE WHEN name = 'b' THEN value END) AS b
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY id
```